# Twilio MessagingResponse class not found in Laravel project on CPanel

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-api

I am working with Twilio on a Laravel project and wrote a function to reply to incoming SMS.
I tested the function on the local machine and it works well. And I uploaded the whole project to CPanel.
All other functions work well but it gets an error like this.

```
Error: Class 'Twilio\Twiml\MessagingResponse' not found in file /home/user_name/subdomain_directory/app/Http/Controllers/Api/SMSController.php on line 104
```

Other classes such as  `Twilio\Rest\Client`, `Twilio\Security\RequestValidator` work well.

I checked `MessagingResponse.php` file in vendor directory on CPanel.

Following is the code. I really don't know why this happens. I will be very grateful if someone helps me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Twiml\MessagingResponse;

class SMSController extends Controller
{
    protected $twilio_number;
    protected $twilio_sid;
    protected $twilio_auth_token;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->twilio_number = env('TWILIO_PHONE');
        $this->twilio_sid = env('TWILIO_SID');
        $this->twilio_auth_token = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
    }

    public function reply(Request $request) {

        $number_from = $request->input('From');

        $message = "You have received a message from " . $number_from;

        $client = new Client($this->twilio_sid, $this->twilio_auth_token);

        $client->messages->create(
            env("TWILIO_REDIRECT_REPLY_TO"),
            array(
                'from' => $this->twilio_number,
                'body' => $message
            )
        );

        $response = new MessagingResponse();
        return response($response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I change `use Twilio\Twiml\MessagingResponse;` into like this: `use Twilio\TwiML\MessagingResponse;`, it worked.